# Update Node using GData Library

Tags: xcode, ios4, xml-parsing, gdata-api, objective-c-2.0

hi i am working with the Gdata library and i am stuck at one place i want to update a particular data from the xml node. Given below is my code that i am trying to update

```
-(void)UpdateTheXMLNode
{
    NSArray *docdirpath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *fileLoc = [[docdirpath objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SomeXML.xml"];

    NSData *xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileLoc];
    GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc]initWithData:xmlData options:0 error:nil];
    NSArray *a = [doc.rootElement elementsForName:@"row"];
    NSLog(@"data before = %@",[[[a objectAtIndex:0] childAtIndex:1]stringValue]);
   [[[a objectAtIndex:0] childAtIndex:1]setStringValue:@"Yahooo"];

    [a writeToFile:fileLoc atomically:YES];
     NSLog(@"data after = %@",[[[a objectAtIndex:0] childAtIndex:1]stringValue]);

}
```

But alas its now giving me any results so please help me out it.